# Google data layer data not being passed to tag manager assistant

Tags: javascript, magento, google-tag-manager

I have setup a click event to a product page. Every time a customer clicks on a specific product the code below is triggered

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'productClick',
   'ecommerce': {
        'click': {
              'actionField': {'list': 'WP'},
              'products': [{
                   'name': 'data',                    
                   'id': 'data',
                   'price': 'data'
               }]
         }
    }
});
```

I have debugged and the data is actually being pushed the the datalayer however when I use google tag assistant to check the datalayer no data is pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the console instead. It's more reliable and accurate. After your dataLayer push, type "dataLayer" and you should see the entire dataLayer:

[image]

Alternatively, if you go into GTM preview mode, you should also see the dataLayer there as well.

[image]